# Creating a new div for each data block in ReactJS using Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am representing the data using redux in React. It gives a DIV for each block of data. I would like to separate each div, space in between each one, and create an accordion card with each div. I am not sure the best way of going about something like this, and using it with redux. The block of code is below.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
// import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import './reasearchPage.style.scss'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
// import { Card, Feed } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import {fetchDataSuccess} from "../../Redux/actions/dataAction";


class ResearchPage extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchDataSuccess();
    }

    render() {
        const { data } = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                <h1 className='page-title'>Record MetaData</h1>

                {data.map(({ id, _index, ContentTypeId}) => (
                    <div key={id} className="query-div">
                        <h3>{_index}</h3>
                        <p>{ContentTypeId}</p>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        );

    }
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    data: state.data.data
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    fetchDataSuccess: () => fetchDataSuccess(dispatch)
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ResearchPage);
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but i think what you're trying to do is creating column(or a row) that its children component have an specific space between them if i understood correctly, right?

Comment: That is what I though at first, however, I am not wanting to strictly tabularize the data. I would like to style it and make it more of an accordion panel with a card. However, in looking at the docs and information on it I could not seem to figure out its use, in terms of passing the data to it.

Comment: Could you show an example of what you trying to achieve  And also the docs that you mentioned? then  may i ask is your problem in passing the data or creating the accordion?

Comment: Yes, give me just a moment.

Comment: something similar to this. Of course I would change the look of it, but the principle component is what I am shooting for. I would like to be able to pass data into the title/header, and then pass data into the body. Please let me know if I can clarify.

https://smellycode.com/accordion-in-reactjs/

Comment: I can not seem to find anything about passing data in the docs. Maybe I am missing something. https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/accordion/

Comment: @yahyaparvar I did get the example to fire, however, passing data into the fields is proving to be problematic. Can you give an example passing the data?

Comment: no need to passing data , just try to put the data in curly braces to accordion like the example `{ContentTypeId}`

Comment: When you use the map function on a list you can get access to the data, so when you want to create components according to a list use map function inside the component and in map function return a child for each element of map, also i updated the answer, chekc if it works and tell me the result

Comment: I am getting a button with my data, and a body with my data, however the button will not toggle it open and closed? Any ideas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228029/discussion-between-damon-ponder-and-yahya-parvar).

Comment: Check this article to learn more https://www.freakyjolly.com/react-bootstrap-accordion-with-customized-style-and-active-panel-style-example/#.YBTrxegzbIU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i checked document and if you're using mentioned library you should define the accordion and use map function inside it and pass the data to the card

```
 <Accordion>
    {data.map(( id, _index, ContentTypeId) => (
  <Card>
    <Card.Header>
      <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="0">
        {id}
      </Accordion.Toggle>
    </Card.Header>
    <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
      <Card.Body>Hello! I'm the body</Card.Body>
    </Accordion.Collapse>
  </Card>))}
</Accordion>
```